# How to distinguish [i] from [iː] in Cyrillic?

Tags: transliteration

[Renglish/Рэнглиш](https://www.omniglot.com/conscripts/renglish.htm) (not mine)
is an adaptation of Cyrillic for English. Most of the sounds seem ok, but how would you normally differentiate [i] in b**i**t from the [iː] in b**ee**t using Cyrillic or would they both just use 'И'?
The sample text they give is:

Ал Хйюмън бееингз ар борн фри энд еекўъл ин Дигнити энд Райтз. Ђей ар ендауед ўић Реезън энд Каншънс энд шюдд якт тъўордс ўун ънуђер ин ей Спирит ъв Бруђергхюд.

In the Latin alphabet that is:

All human beings are born free and equal in dignity and rights. They are endowed with reason and conscience and should act towards one another in a spirit of brotherhood. (Universal declaration of human rights)

I know some characters are very differenṭ from their normal sounds, like я for 'æ' instead of 'ja' & ц for dʒ 'ts' (стяк ексчэнц would be 'stack exchange'.) I use џ instead of ц for dʒ. I thought about using ы for [i] and и for

Comment: Your question is not about linguistics, it's about constructed scripts, so you'd better ask it at https://conlang.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I though about posting it there but I figured they'd say the same thing because it's not really about a constructed script either. It's about transliteration. I picked this community because it has to do with pronunciation so I though linguistics was a better fit. I can post it there, but I suspect they'll say it doesn't belong there too.

Comment: It is exactly a constructed script, it's not a transliteration, it looks a bit like an alternative transcription method, but it's far from being either phonetic or phonological. Besides, no way one is expected to read the Serbian letters `ћ` and `ђ` as [θ] and [ð], or `ё` as [ei] and `ю` as [uː], ascribing those phonetic values to those letters is absolutely arbitrary. And that capitalization of nouns. A conscript it is, don't argue with an experienced conscripter. :P

Comment: Maybe 'transliteration' isn't the correct word to use, but I don't consider an adaptation of an existing script to write another language a constructed script, so I guess we have different ideas of what a 'constructed script' is. I'm not trying to argue & I didn't know you we're an "experienced conscripter".

Comment: Yes, we have different ideas of what a 'constructed script' is. What do you think, a Cesar cypher is also "an adaptation of an existing script"? If you mix up the values of letters you construct a new writing system. Besides, according to you, the Cyrillic alphabet is not a constructed script, it's just a way to write Slavic languages with Greek letters. Still, Cyrillic _is_ a distinct alphabet, just the same way as that Renglish is a distinct alphabet. Mind that your question here is asking for help in _constructing_ a more consistent version of Renglish.

Comment: @jastako Cyrillic is not a single alphabet with unambiguous sounds. English i-ee could be close to any of ы-и,і-и,и-ий,и-иј depending on language. You're right about ц vs џ (Macedonian ѓ is close too, just a bit softer). For æ i would also consider [ѣ (yat)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yat) - historically it was pronounced [æ:] before it split into я (which is the only borrowing from Latin - a reversed R) and е. I agree with Yellow Sky about ћђёю. Why not use [ѳ (fita)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fita) for "th"?